# DateSignedTabs & FullNameTabs not working when bound to form fields

Tags: .net, docusignapi

I'm creating an envelope with .net core project. I'm using a PDF document and modified https://github.com/docusign/eg-01-csharp-jwt-framework project. Idea is to us signature field for signing and to automatically set sign date & full name of the signer in other two fields.
PDF fields with names:
[image]

I'm using composite template with one inline template and one document.
TransformPdfFields is ON:

```
Document doc1 = CreateDocumentFromTemplate("1", "Subscription document", "pdf", DSHelper.ReadContent(DOC_1_PDF));
doc1.TransformPdfFields = "true";
```

Tabs are created like this:

```
signer.Tabs = new Tabs
{
   SignHereTabs = new List<SignHere>() { signHere },
   DateSignedTabs = new List<DateSigned>() { dateSign },
   FullNameTabs = new List<FullName>() { fullName }
};
```

SignHere is using existing PDF fields and it is working:
    return new SignHere
    {
       TabLabel = fieldName,
       RecipientId = recipientId
    };

However DateSigned & FullName are not working with fields:

```
private DateSigned CreateDateSign(String fieldName, string recipientId)
{
    return new DateSigned
    {
        TabLabel = fieldName,
        RecipientId = recipientId
    };
}
```

But they are working with anchors:

```
private DateSigned CreateDateSign(String fieldName, string recipientId)
{
    return new DateSigned
    {               
       AnchorString = fieldName,
       AnchorUnits = "pixels",
       AnchorXOffset = "0",
       AnchorYOffset = "15",
       RecipientId = recipientId
     };
 }
enter code here
```

Is it possible to use text fields for those tasks like for signing? I would like to avoid typo errors or/and complex mappings between arbitrary texts and fields.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PDF's FormField name have to be in DocuSign standards as explained [here](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-soap-api/reference/Sending-Group/Rules-for-CompositeTemplate-Usage), check Note1 and Note2 section only. For instance, fullname:

```
Adobe name contains DocuSignFullName or eSignFullName = DocuSign FullName
```

for DateSigned:

```
Adobe name contains DocuSignDateSigned or eSignDateSigned = DocuSign DateSigned
```

Comment: Thanks Amit. I saw those guides but I considered since it was working for sign here with arbitrary field name it will work also for this.

Thanks again